# Select and display an image from the filesystem with electron

Tags: javascript, image, file, electron

I'm developing a little app in Electron from which I can upload an image to Instagram and I'm stuck at one of the first steps :/

I want to select an image from the filesystem and display it in my app.

This is the code I've got so far:

CODE:

```
remote.dialog.showOpenDialog((filenames) => {
    fs.readFile(filepath, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {

        if(err){
            alert("An error ocurred reading the file :" + err.message);
            return;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A minimal example to select, read and display a png image.

Renderer process:::

```js
var remote = require('electron').remote;
var fs = remote.require('fs');

  
remote.dialog.showOpenDialog(remote.getCurrentWindow(),
   {
    filters: [
      {name: 'Images', extensions: ['png']}
    ]
   }, 
   function(filepaths, bookmarks) {
     //read image (note: use async in production)
     var _img = fs.readFileSync(filepaths[0]).toString('base64');
     //example for .png
     var _out = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + _img + '" />';
     //render/display
     var _target = document.getElementById('image_container');
     _target.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', _out);

     return;
});
```

```html
<div id="image_container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using this line fs.readFileSync(filepaths[0]).toString('base64') I can build further from there.

Comment: There is a way to attach file buffer directly to image ? without convert it to `base64`

Comment: document is not defined

Answer (score 17):

Here is a solution with more information on separation of `main` process and `renderer` and usage of `es6`

**main process**

```
import { ipcMain, dialog } from "electron";
import fs from 'fs';

ipcMain.on("chooseFile", (event, arg) => {
  const result = dialog.showOpenDialog({
    properties: ["openFile"],
    filters: [{ name: "Images", extensions: ["png","jpg","jpeg"] }]
  });

  result.then(({canceled, filePaths, bookmarks}) => {
    const base64 = fs.readFileSync(filePaths[0]).toString('base64');
    event.reply("chosenFile", base64);
  });
});
```

**renderer process**

```
import electron from 'electron';

// trigger file prompt
electron.ipcRenderer.send('chooseFile');

// handle response
electron.ipcRenderer.on('chosenFile', (event, base64) => {
  const src = `data:image/jpg;base64,${base64}`
})
```

Comment: thanks. this was way more relatable and understandable for me

Comment: use handle/invoke instead of on/send will make it more clear

Answer (score 8):

With electron 11 the following snippet from https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/protocol  works

```
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  protocol.registerFileProtocol('atom', (request, callback) => {
    console.log(request.url)
    const url = request.url.substr(7)
    callback({ path: url })
  })
})
```

Be careful **not** to use the usual `file://` protocol, but the custom 'atom' or 'my_whatever' protocol instead

You can now get the image this way :

```
<img src="atom://C:\\Users\\my_path\\myfile.png" />
```

However if you wan't to keep the syntaxe of the `file` protocol in the render side, you can do the following :

```
protocol.registerFileProtocol('file', ()=>...)
```

Now you can get an image this way

```
<img src="file://C:\\Users\\my_path\\myfile.png" />
```

However you will have to disable `webSecurity`

```
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
webPreferences: {
  nodeIntegration : true,
  webSecurity: false
}
```

Comment: This is a way better solution

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `file://` protocol is disabled. As such, you must *register your own protocol*. Thanks to nicoNx for his answer which included the link to the electron protocol docs. The following code is a direct copy from the Electron docs: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/protocol

```js
const { app, protocol } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  protocol.registerFileProtocol('atom', (request, callback) => {
    const filePath = url.fileURLToPath('file://' + request.url.slice('atom://'.length))
    callback(filePath)
  })
})
```

Then in your html:

```html
<img src="atom://[FILE_ADDRESSS]" />
```

If your experience problems, make sure you are attaching the protocol to the correct browser session. You can find more details on how to manage your browser sessions in the electron protocol docs (link above). Also make sure you register the protocol "after" the app is ready.

Answer (score 0):

set webSecurity to false in your browserwindow settings.

```
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      ...your prev settings
    webPreferences: {
      ...your prev settings
      webSecurity: false, // to load local imgs
   }
  });
```

Then in your renderer you can put src as `path.join('file://', ${ur local image path})` and it will work.